# Need explanations of this hell-like syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I took this sample from the official doc https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

```
 return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
 };
```

How i'm supposed to understand this ?

```
 return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    return ...
 }
```

It seems to return a javascript object (control : object) but then why there is a lambda ?

The problem is not what the function do, which is explained in the doc, but the syntax of the return statement.

Edit : i just didn't know that you can create a function like that, now it's clear.

Please explain to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a function that has a parameter `control` of type `AbstractControl` (`control: AbstractControl`). This function that is returned will in turn return an object that can be indexed by string and the values in the object are of type any (`{[key: string]: any}`). The retuned function is an arrow function (`=>`)